# Get "unexpected token" when I render a component

Tags: reactjs

The browser says there's an `unexpected token` when I try to render the App component. I used the correct syntax when calling the component, but I still get an error. If I called the component incorrectly then I would get error message before the browser would get to the end of the file because I call all the rest of the components the same way. This is a screenshot of the message I get from the browser in addition to my JavaScript and html file.

[image: Error message in the console]

```js
{/*how to create react comment*/}
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
        <h1>Scoreboard</h1>
        <span className= "stats">Players: 1</span>
    </header>
    )
}

const Player = () => {
return (
  <div className= "player">

      <span className="player-name">Chris</span>
      <Counter />
  </div>

)

}

const Counter = () => {
 return (
   <div className="counter">

       <button className="counter-action decrement"> - </button>
       <span className="counter-score">Chris</span>
       <button className="counter-action increment"> + </button>

   </div>
 )

}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="scoreboard">

       <Header />
    {/*players list*/}
       <Player />
    </div>



  )
}



ReactDOM.render(
{/*the element we want*/}
<App />,
{/*the element we want to append on to*/}
document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Scoreboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css" />
  </head>
<!-- have to go to a local server http://localhost:8000/ to view your work.
this will have the port 8000, if you want another project on a local server do "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7800" that will direct it
to port 7800. have to keep command prompt open to use the local server.takes a minute to load -->
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, please solution below. if you need any other help. let me know

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your comments from `ReactDOM.render()`

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

don't pass any comments inside `ReactDOM.render()`.

syntax

> ReactDOM.render(reactElement, domContainerNode)

for your reference please refer to [Reactjs documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html)

Comment: @Paine8887 if answer is helpful for you please accept/vote for this.